# What does this character mean in an SQL query?

Tags: sql

```
<>
```

What does this character mean when placed in an SQL query?

Comment: At least some reading of TSQL syntax helps... Operators would immediately get you there. Especially if you looked at TSQL you'd see it's some sort of an operation leading you to operators...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the SQL way of writing the `not equal` operator.

Answer (score 2):

This means "not equal" operator in SQL query ie`select * from firstname <> 'james'` this means give me all rows whose first name not equal to james

Answer (score 1):

It's the SQL operator for "not equal", though many databases also provide the (non standard) `!=` operator that means exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

this means 'Not Equal Operator.' ......!!!!!

Just as `!=` in c and other languages. `<>` is for SQL

Answer (score 0):

this operator means not equal ....

Answer (score 0):

Not equal, i.e. Less than or greater than.